# XSLT - Hyphen in XML root element

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT is not finding the root element if it has hyphen in it:

```
<serial-issue>
    <title>hello</title>
    <issue-info>
        <pii>3426-4114(11)X6013-4</pii>
        <jid>Journal</jid>
        <issn>1526-4114</issn>
    </issue-info>
</serial-issue>
```

Here is the XSLT script:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="serial-issue"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="issue-info">
    <test>
    <xsl:value-of select="jid"/>
</test>
</xsl:template>
```

The above script is not working. It works if 'serial-issue' is changed to 'serialissue'. Can you please help?

Comment: Either the samples provided are incorrect, or you have a very basic XSLT parser. This can't work...

Comment: You have an undeclared namespace 'ce' and your `<test>` node isn't closed....

Comment: The name of your root node shouldn't be the problem, though. Once the issues I mention above are fixed, I can do the transformation without any problems (I'm using Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: I have made the changes. I am still unable to make this one work.

Comment: What are you using as processor? And what do you mean by 'unable to make this one work'? Any errors?

Comment: This is the output I am getting:

<html>
   <body></body>
</html>

I am using Saxon9 processor. If I change the root tag to 'serialissue', I get the following output:

<html>
   <body>
      hello
      
      <test>Journal</test>
      
   </body>
</html>

The hyphen in the root tag is the issue here. Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: At a minimum, you need to add a complete XSLT example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Otherwise, I doubt anyone can reproduce this.

Comment: The script got cut off because I did not add space before the codes properly. I have found out an alternative solution. It is not the root tag. The issue is with the DTD. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

In this example a template is called for with the match of 'serial-issue' but there is no such template.

Adding

```
<xsl:template match="serial-issue">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

to your XSL script would solve the issue.
Furthermore  is not an HTML tag, so it will have not function in the output.

The minimal version of the stylesheet may look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:output method="html"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
     <html><body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
     </body></html>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="serial-issue">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="issue-info">
       <xsl:value-of select="jid"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: "*Adding ... to your XSL script would solve the issue.*" No, it wouldn't.